# There are three things in the world that smell like fish. But why?

Tags: smell

As a philospher once said, there are three things in the world that smell like fish. One of them is fish.

What connects these three things that gives them this particular, characteristic smell? What chemical exactly do we smell?

Comment: Small alkyl amines, particularly trimethylamine.